# PrimeNG BlockUI occasionally not blocking although block flag is true?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am observing strange behavior from primeng 13.4.1 / angular version 13.2.1. This is after upgrading angular many major versions.

In certain circumstances, BlockUI is not blocking even when the boolean block flag is true. The BlockUI is only covering this particular component occasionally, and is not aligned with the boolean flag that [blocked] is set to. Please see below. I have observed this issue only with a few components.

The component:

```
``<div>
  <p-blockUI [blocked]=this.blockUpdatingPage [target]="blocked4" styleClass="overlayZindex">
    <i class="fa fa-lock fa-4x" style="position:absolute;top:25%;left:50%"></i>
  </p-blockUI>
<p-fieldset #blocked4 [hidden]="hideSaveAndUpdate">
  <p> {{ shouldItBeBlocked() }}</p>
  <p-header>7. Save & Update</p-header>
  <div [hidden]="!createNew">
    <br/>
    <p-progressBar mode="indeterminate" [style]="{'height': '6px'}" *ngIf="loadingBar"></p-progressBar>
    <span class="ui-float-label">
        <input [(ngModel)]="inputText" id="float-input" maxlength="200" pInputText type="text">
       <label for="float-input">Create new...</label>
      </span>
    <button (click)="checkIfBenchmarkIsSelectedCreateNew()" [disabled]= "disabledFlag"  align="center" label="Save & Continue" pButton
            style="background-color:#215A8F"></button>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="createNew == true">
    <br/>
    <button (click)="checkIfThingSelected(false)" [disabled]= "disabledFlag || blockUpdatingPage" label="Update '{{this.selectedThing}}'" pButton
            align="center" style="background-color:#215A8F"></button>
    <br/>
  </div>
</p-fieldset>
</div>`
`
```

Function proving that the blockUI is not working... always.

```
`  shouldItBeBlocked() {
    if (this.blockUpdatingPage === false) {
      return 'it should not be blocked now';
    } else {
      return 'it should be blocked now';
    }
  }
}
```

`

Showing three cases -

[image: Correct f:unctionality]

[image: Correct functionality, not blocked.]
[image: Incorrect functionality. the flag is true, but "display:none" is set for blockui component....]

Tried to understand why the display:none would be set for blockui component. The source code shows that it should be set to display:flex whenever the flag is true.

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause of this problem was that I had a

```
// cdr = ChangeDetectorRef
cdr.detectChanges();
```

after setting the "blocked" property to true/false. We added this as a workaround for an "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked" error. Removing this fixed the problem of the overlay not always appearing, even though "blocked" was true.